# Facebook page impersonation failed: page token is the same as user token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, impersonation

I try to post on Facebook page with impersonation and for that, I use the page access token, but it seems this page token is the same than user access token (which is the page administrator).

When I post via the Graph API, it does work perfectly (page feed is updated). When I execute the same request via my test application, it is treated as "user" XXX posted on page feed.

Thus the impersonation failed. If someone knows the workaround, please share.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should post your code if you need help on that

Answer (score 1):

have you requested your page token from the endpoint : 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/accounts/' with the token of the admin? .. because my pagetokens are not equal to user-tokens..

Comment: Yes with this request 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/accounts/' , the access token field of page is the same as my access token.

Comment: maybe try to get a new user token/ long lived user token and request again an page-token... otherwise i don´t know... in my code which runs properly is nothing special.. http GET to the right endpoint and adding access_token and appsecret_proof

Comment: I have already tried that and I get the same result. In fact I can post on the page and with the Graph API  I post with the access token field of page and with my test application, it posts with the user-token. Do you have another idea about what to do ? ;)